# What technique is used to draw the lifelike backgrounds in the movie Ponyo?

Tags: anime-production, ponyo

In the movie [*Ponyo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponyo), the backgrounds (the clouds, pictured below) are not done in a typical anime style. Instead, they are much more lifelike and 3D.

[image]

What is the technique used to do this? Is this used in other films or series?

Comment: Hmm, I'd say borderline off-topic in favour of graphic design

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'd agree it's a bit close to the edge, but I didn't worry about that too much as it's specific to this movie (and, more generally, Miyazaki productions). It's also not "How do I do this?" but rather "What did this anime artist used to achieve said effect?" I'd be open to a meta or chat discussion about it, though.

Comment: Well, since we haven't had any close votes, I'd say people agree with you. Carry on :)

Comment: You might found this interesting, it's a real-time demonstration of the man who painted "Totoro" backgrounds. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1bCIkKQm0U

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are good old hand-drawn backgrounds. Here's a part of [an interview](http://www.ghibliworld.com/suzuki_toshio_interview.html) with Suzuki Toshio, executive producer and former president of Studio Ghibli (emphasis mine):

> During this decade CG *[computer graphics, - singerofthefall]* came up and we realized that it enables us to
>   make expressions richer when using it as supplement of regular cel *[sic!]*
>   animation. On the other hand a new problem appeared. The progress of
>   computing tech is so fast that it isn't easy to catch up. If a movie
>   at one point is made by the highest tech, it will become outdated
>   soon. There is one more point. We tried CG on Howl’s. For example, the
>   legs of the castle were made by CG. However, it didn't seem very
>   natural to me and I told Miyazaki that his skill was better than that
>   of a computer. He accepted it and quit using CG after that. Hence the
>   latter half of Howl’s doesn't include any CG. We now know CG has both
>   its plus and minus sides. So the theme of this movie is as the story:
>   simple. The visual effects are simple as well, while on the other hand
>   **it needs very hard working because of the drawing all it by hand.**

It is also mentioned [here](http://www.utsandiego.com/news/2009/aug/14/us-film-hayao-miyazaki-081409/):

> Miyazaki, whose films include "Princess Mononoke," "Howl's Moving
>   Castle" and "My Neighbor Totoro," has used computer animation to
>   embellish hand-drawn images. But before "Ponyo" went into production,
>   **he shut down the computer-graphics department at his Studio Ghibli,
>   opting to work solely in hand-drawn images.**

And finally, from [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/6911264/Hayao-Miyazaki-drawn-to-perfection.html) article:

> He insisted he still uses a pencil to draw his animated characters and
>   backgrounds: “Currently computer graphics are used a great deal,” he
>   noted, “but it can be excessive. I think [animation] needs the pencil,
>   needs man’s hands drawing.”

I would recommend you to check some of Makoto Shinkai's works (if you haven't seen them before) the quality of the animation and backgrounds there is stunning.

**Update**:
There is an artbook called "The Art of Ponyo", which contains sketches hand-drawn by Miyazaki. I don't own it, but you can take a look at it's reviews [here](http://www.parkablogs.com/content/book-review-art-of-ponyo-cliff-sea), [here](http://cdn.halcyonrealms.com/animation/the-art-of-ponyo-part-i-storyboards/) and [here](http://cdn.halcyonrealms.com/anime/the-art-of-ponyo-part-ii-concept-and-background-art/). The book includes both pencil and watercolor drawings, including characters, backgrounds, etc:

> Usually I use poster paint to create the backgrounds; then I color the
>   base in a pale color, adding subtle hues and shading on top of it.
>   This time, with Ponyo, I added things like tints or detailed
>   expressions with colored pencil on top of what I drew with poster
>   paint...

Comment: This seems to cover most of the basics, but doesn't touch on what the technique is beyond the hand sketches. Is it pencil crayons, crayons, or maybe a specific type of painting (watercolor, acrylic)?

Comment: @Eric, I've updated the answer, hope it helps. There isn't much information about the production of the movie in the Internet (at least in English, maybe there is some in Japanese, but I don't know Japanese), so that's about all I was able to find.

Comment: Good advice! I found a quote from the book which you may want to add to your answer: "*Usually I use poster paint to create the backgrounds; then I color the base in a pale color, adding subtle hues and shading on top of it. This time, with Ponyo, I added things like tints or detailed expressions with colored pencil on top of what I drew with poster paint...*"

Comment: @Eric, nice quote, thanks :P added it to the answer.

Comment: The bit about inclusion/exclusion CG is more relevant about moving objects, the OP asks about _backgrounds_.